# Does CAM::PDFsupport Identity-H style of encoding ? How to decode it or how to change encoding style in pdf using perl

Tags: perl, pdf

CAM::PDFsupports Identity-H style of encoding ?...I think not, How to decode the encoding style, in order to parse the pdf.